# Convert PERL Regex to Golang RE2

Tags: regex, go

I am aware that lookaround is not supported in Golang however I can't get my head around the conversion.

REGEX:   ^(?!d-)([\da-zA-Z]+)([-]*[\da-zA-Z])*$

Answer (score 1):

After looking around I think @tshiono idea is the one that makes the most sense but the regex was not matching what I was expecting.
I ended up with something like this

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

func main() {
    st := []string{
       "test-adccount",
       "s-asdgaysdtuaystdua",
       "2342348jtdstyfu",
       "kdshkjfshdkfjhd-jkshdfjkshdf",
       "uysiufysdusidyf-jsdkhfjksdhf",
       "ausyduaysidyaisyd",
       "2abc-f",
       "d-23423423",
       "-iasodaisdyauiysd",
       "sudyfisdufy82|ldjf",
       "klskdjfsd898883---sdfkjskdfjsld",
   }

for _, s := range st {
    r1 := regexp.MustCompile(`^([\da-zA-Z]+)([\da-zA-Z-]+)$`)
    r2 := regexp.MustCompile(`^(d-).+$`)

    if r1.MatchString(s) && !r2.MatchString(s) {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s  :: matched", s))
    } else {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s :: does not matched", s))
    }
  }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/j-7INwyDwU4

Answer (score 0):

Positive lookaround assertion can be altered without using `PCRE`, but
negative lookaround cannot. We need to split the regex into two step logics.
For instance, we can say the following in `python`:

```
import re
s = '2abc-D'            # matches
#s = 'd-D'              # doesn't match
m = re.match(r'^(?!d-)([\da-zA-Z]+)(-[\da-zA-Z])$', s)
if (m):
    print(m.groups())
```

In `Golang`, we will need to say:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := "2abc-D"       // matches
    // s := "d-D"       // doesn't match
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`^([\da-zA-Z]+)(-[\da-zA-Z])$`)
    if !(regexp.MustCompile(`^d-`).MatchString(s)) {
        fmt.Println(r.FindStringSubmatch(s))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Your idea makes total sense however the regex was not the one I expected. Please see the orignal REGEX https://regex101.com/r/eFb0pn/1 and your answer only matched one of the strings instead of some of them https://regex101.com/r/4fY2yj/1.
Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm afraid your mentioned regex differs from the one in the original post :). But your answer seems to work well. Good job!